# subprocess call with argparse

Tags: python, directory, subprocess, argparse

The structure of folder directory is as follows:

```
folder_A
folder_A/a.py
folder_A/subfolder_AA/b.py
folder_A/subfolder_AA/subsubfolder_testvideos/a.avi
```

a.py looks like...

```
import cv2
import argparse as ap

def run(source=0, dispLoc=False):
    cam=cv2.VideoCapture(source)
    while True:
        ret, img = cam.read()
        if not ret:
            exit()
        if(cv2.waitKey(10)==ord('p')):
            break
        cv2.imshow("image",img)
    cv2.destroyWindow("image")

# Other scripts here....
if __name__ =="__main__":
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('-d', "--deviceID", help="Device ID")
    group.add_argument('-v', "--videoFile", help="Path to Video File")
    parser.add_argument('-l', "--dispLoc", dest="dispLoc", 
    action="store_true")
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())

    if args["videoFile"]:
        source = args["videoFile"]
    else:
        source = int(args["deviceID"])

    run(source, args["dispLoc"])
```

a.py tries to import and run b, and b needs argparse.

If I simply run b.py from the terminal, the command of running b will be

```
python b.py -v subsubfolder_testvideos/a.avi
```

I am trying to run a.py and make b.py run inside it.

In the a.py file, I wrote the codes like below.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('~/Desktop/folder_A')
sys.path.append('~/Desktop/')
from os import system
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["python", "b.py","-v testvideos/a.avi"], cwd="/subfolder_AA/", shell=True)
```

and the output error is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/subfolder_AA/': '/subfolder_AA/'

Is this error coming from my faulty command using subprocess.call? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're doing an absolute file path when you prefix the folder with `/`.

Second, you should use regular python imports instead of subprocess calls. You should put an `__init__.py` in the subfolder to be able to import from it. Then you can modify `b.py` so it passes the arguments from the `ArgumentParser` to another function that is then imported by `a.py`. Something like:

`b.py`:

```
def process_video(device_id=None, video_file=None):
    # ...do stuff...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    # ...etc...
    return process_video(device_id=parser.deviceid, video_file=parser.videofile)
```

`a.py`:

```
from subfolder_AA.b import process_video

processed_video = process_video(video_file='testvideos/a.avi')
```

Comment: Thanks! If b is importing c.py in the same directory, do I need to change the line 'import c'?

Comment: Oh I figured it out! 'import subfolder_AA.b as ots and ots.run("testvideos/1.avi")!!